# Thymeleaf-Layout-Dialect didn't decorate

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I've used attritubte Decorate in Thymeleaf-Layout-Dialect to create file index2.html,the program runs normally, but it's not success to Decorate file index2.html.
Here is my code
File "**Build.graddle**"
`

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.6'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.15.RELEASE'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-layout-dialect:3.0.0'
'

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    runtimeOnly 'com.mysql:mysql-connector-j'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

`

File **_layout.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">
<head>
  <title>Layout page</title>
  <script src="common-script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <h1>My website</h1>
  </header>
  <section layout:fragment="content">
    <p>Page content goes here</p>
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

File **index2.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
  layout:decorate="~{_layout.html}">
<head>
  <title>Content page</title>
  <script src="content-script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <section layout:fragment="content">
    <p>This is a paragraph from the content page</p>
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

What should I do to solve this problem ? Thanks a lot

Comment: Did you find any solution? I'm having a very similar problem.